# C++ crash occur when calling delete on a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error

I have written a small program using struct and pointers(->). So I have declared an object pointer which point to another object from the same struct. But when ever delete is invoked on  the application would just crash.

Here is the error

```
Debug Assertion Failed
File:f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_86x\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp
Line 52
Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead -> nBlockUse)
```

And here is my code also (p.s This error does not occur when I removed delete from my program)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//declare structure to store info about Billy
struct Son{
    string name;
    string crush;
    int age;
    string hobbies[3];
}Person;

int main(){
    string sAge;
    int i;
    Son* info = new Son;
    info = &Person;
    //user interface
    //Person's name
    cout << "Person's name: ";
    getline(cin, info ->name); //inputs person's name
    //Person's age
    cout << "Person's age: ";
     //inputs person's age
    getline(cin,sAge);
    stringstream ss;
    ss << sAge;
    ss >> info->age;
    info->age = atoi(sAge.c_str());
    //for loop to get hobbies
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << "Write your hobby[" << i <<"]: ";
        getline(cin,info ->hobbies[i]); //inputs the person hobby three times
    }
    //Person's crush
    cout << "Write your crush name: ";
    getline(cin, info ->crush); //inputs the person's crush *opitional*

    //output statement
    cout << "Name: " << info ->name << endl; //display name
    cout << "Age: " << info ->age << endl; //display age
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){ //display hobbies
    cout << "Hobbies[" << j << "]: " << info ->hobbies[j] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Crush: " << info ->crush << endl; //display crush
    cout << "Deleting memory" << endl;
    delete info;
    info = NULL;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and based on my own knowledge (please correct me if I am wrong)

```
Son* info = new Son;
```

This pointer (info) has a new syntax and should be deleted like this

```
delete info;
```

And not really sure why did I get this error

Comment: This looks like a typo error here, you set info to pointer to non dynamically allocated memory here `info = &Person;`

Comment: You should better use `std::unique_ptr<Son>` or `std::shared_ptr<Son>` to get this running correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do this

```
info = &Person;
```

you make `info` point to an object that is not dynamically allocated. So you can't call delete on it. Besides that, you leak the newed `Son` object it originally pointed to. In any case, there seems to be no reason to use dynamic allocation in your code example.